# Quartz 2D Path rotation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, quartz-2d

I'm fairly new to Quartz 2D.

Imagine the following scenario:

You have a circle-shaped mini map view.
I'm drawing triangle (the arc isn't important right now) on top of the map. This shape represents the visible area.

I need to have the triangle shape rotate along the mini map as the user changes orientation.

Currently this how the path is being drawn:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleInRadians);

CGPath visibleAreaPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(visibleAreaPath, &transform, miniMapCenter.x, miniMapCenter.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(visibleAreaPath, &transform, 18.0, 8.0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(visibleAreaPath, &transform, 66.0, 8.0);

CGPathCloseSubpath(visibleAreaPath);
```

I then draw the path using a CAShapeLayer like so:

```
CALayer *rootLayer = [visibleAreaView layer];

visibleAreaShape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[visibleAreaShape setFillColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:0.584 saturation:0.8 brightness:0.9 alpha:0.6].CGColor];
[visibleAreaShape setFillRule:kCAFillRuleNonZero];
[visibleAreaShape setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];
[rootLayer addSublayer:visibleAreaShape];
[visibleAreaShape setPath:visibleAreaPath];
```

The path is being rotated, but not based on a given origin.
Keep in mind that setting the layer's anchor point doesn't help me since what I want is to rotate the path (ultimately I wouldn't even need to display it, since I will be using it to determine which points are visible on the mini map).

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that the path always rotate to the same angle relative to the superview? In other words, the rotations are not accumulative?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you store the points in polar form and convert to a path when needed. It's very easy to rotate in polar coordinates (simply change the theta value).